# Unable to see logs in Jersey Test Framework Enabled via TestProperties class

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jersey-2.0, jersey-test-framework

I'm trying to run tests using maven for Jersey Test Framework, In this code basically I'm trying to test a resource, I also wanted to dump the entity to the console and also look at the log traffic for the kind of request I'm getting ... Here is the sample of my code that I wrote.

```
package in.swapnilsingh;

import in.swapnilsingh.entity.Book;
import org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.logging.LoggingFeature;
import org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.JerseyTest;
import org.glassfish.jersey.test.TestProperties;
import org.junit.Test;

import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertNotNull;

public class BookResourceTest extends JerseyTest {

    @Override
    protected Application configure() {
        enable(TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC);
        enable(TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY);
        return new ResourceConfig().packages("in.swapnilsingh");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configureClient(ClientConfig config) {

        config.register(new LoggingFeature(Logger.getAnonymousLogger(), Level.INFO, LoggingFeature.Verbosity.PAYLOAD_TEXT, 1500));
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetBook() {
        Book response = target("books").path("1").request().get(Book.class);
        assertNotNull(response);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetBooks() {
        Collection<Book> response = target("books").request().get(new GenericType<Collection<Book>>() {
        });
        assertEquals(3, response.size());
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `configure()` method I'm enabling `TestProperties.LOG_TRAFFIC` & `TestProperties.DUMP_ENTITY` ... Still I'm not able to get the desired output in the logs. I'm also attaching the logs below.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java.exe" -Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=D:\IdeaProjects\books "-Dmaven.home=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3" "-Dclassworlds.conf=C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\bin\m2.conf" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=59253:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2019.1.2\plugins\maven\lib\maven3\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar" org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version2019.1.2 test
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building books 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ books ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\IdeaProjects\books\src\main\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ books ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ books ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory D:\IdeaProjects\books\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ books ---
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to D:\IdeaProjects\books\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ books ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: D:\IdeaProjects\books\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running in.swapnilsingh.BookResourceTest
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating GrizzlyTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:9998]
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer] Started.
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:9998]
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating GrizzlyTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:9998]
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer-1] Started.
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:9998]
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.908 sec
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.jersey.test.grizzly.GrizzlyTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyTestContainer <init>
INFO: Creating GrizzlyTestContainer configured at the base URI http://localhost:9998/
Running in.swapnilsingh.MyResourceTest
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener start
INFO: Started listener bound to [localhost:9998]
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer start
INFO: [HttpServer-2] Started.
May 13, 2019 6:41:03 PM org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.NetworkListener shutdownNow
INFO: Stopped listener bound to [localhost:9998]
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.047 sec

Results :

Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 2.553 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-05-13T18:41:04+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 17M/207M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Process finished with exit code 0
```